# Where to set Maximum Id of Primary Key in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-sql-data-modeler

Where to set Maximum Id of Primary Key in Oracle SQL Developer?
I have seeded some data Production DB to Lower Environment. But In production Maximum ID is more than million. So I want set Million as the Current maximum ID of the Primary Key in one of the Lower Environment table. Now it is failing with Maximum ID is already existing.

I have seeded some data Production DB to Lower Environment. But In production Maximum ID is more than million. So I want set Million as the Current maximum ID of the Primary Key in one of the Lower Environment table. Now it is failing with Maximum ID is already existing.

Comment: What is the Primary Key? A regular sequence? An identity?

Comment: Assume Max id of a primary key in prod is 100k+. Befote loading in lower environment max id of primary key is 90k-. Assume After seeding 20k records to Lower environment maximum value 110k. So I need to set maximum id manually with 110k.

Comment: Sorry, but you haven't answered my question. I don't think it's possible for us to tell you how to approach this if you can't tell tell us if it's a sequence or identity since each has different rules. There is also a matter of the unknown questions raised by Littlefoot.

Comment: Ok. NP. But there is some place in Backend where we can change Maximum ID of Primary key to 110K. Once I get answer I will add the steps to change it here.

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere, as far as I can tell. It is you who should pay attention to what you're inserting into target environment, either

- when "exporting" data from production, or
- when "importing" data into *lower environment* (whatever that means)

You didn't explain how you did that - if you used `select` statement to create a CSV file, you'd e.g.

```
select ...
from production_Table
where id <= 1e6         -- restrict IDs to at most 1 million
```

or - while inserting data into the target - do

```
insert into lower_environment_table
select ... from ...
where id <= 1e6
```

---

It would be even easier if databases are in the same network so that you could create a **database link** and directly copy data from one environment to another.

If you used **Data Pump** export and import utilities, you could apply the `where` clause so that .dmp file already contains rows you want which would then simplifiy import.

On the other hand, if you don't care about possible duplicates (which are prevented by primary key constraint anyway, as it won't allow them), insert would simply *fail* and you'd ignore all those errors.

Basically, the final "answer" depends on the way you're performing that process.

Comment: It is not by query. It is some where in table properties.